# Flatness of fixed points scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a flat morphism of algebraic varieties (let's say over $\mathbb C$).
You can assume that $Y$ is smooth and $X$ is normal.

Assume that $X$ has a fiberwise action of the multiplicative group $\mathbb G_m$.
Consider the fixed points scheme $X^{\mathbb G_m}$

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Is it true that $X^{\mathbb G_m}$ is automatically flat over $Y$? I am especially interested in the case when we know that the map $X^{\mathbb G_m}\to Y$ is finite.

Comment: For nonfinite morphisms I think that the answer is no. You could take $Y = Spec(\mathbb{C}[t])$ and $X = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x,y,t]/(xy-t))$ where the variable $x$ has grading -1 and $y$ had grading $1$. Then there is a single fixed point over the origin in $Y$. I would need to think more about the finite case.

Comment: Actually, about the finite case. By working locally we can suppose $Y = Spec(A)$ and $X = Spec(B)$ is a finite graded $Y$ algebra that is also a domain. There are finitely many possible weights for elements of B, because we get a finitely many direct summands in the grading as $A$-modules. If $B$ is a domain and the grading is nontrivial, then taking powers of a homogeneous element with nonzero grading would yield inifinitely many homogeneous elements with distinct gradings, a contradiction.

Comment: In other words, I think that $X$ being a variety (integral) and the map being finite implies that any fiberwise $\mathbb{G}_m$-action is necessarily trivial. (Unless I am making a mistake). This would solve the question in the finite case positively (trivially).

Comment: That is not true without further hypotheses.  For instance, begin with the standard action of the multiplicative group on the projective line, and form the product of the projective line with $Y$ together with its projection to $Y$.  Now let $D$ be an effective Cartier divisor in $Y$.  Let $X$ be the blowing up of the product along $\{0\}\times $D$.

Comment: I realize now that my example is very similar to the example by @afh.

Comment: In the positive direction, if you assume that the morphism from $X$ to $Y$ is a smooth morphism, this follows from Iversen’s Theorem.

Comment: If you allow $X$ to be singular, you can produce even worse examples than the ones by@afh and myself.

Comment: Yes, the examples seem similar. Also, ooops, I just realized that the op was interested about the case when $X^{\mathbb{G}_m} \to Y$ is finite. I misread and replaced it with "$X \to Y$ is finite". Please ignore my two latter comments.